# How to solve this Cauchy problem?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, cauchy-problem

The PDE is

$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = u+1$

With $u(x,y) = x^2$ on $y = x^2$

The characteristic equations are

$\frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y} = \frac{du}{u+1}$

Integrating the characteristic equations I get that $C_1 = 0$ and that $C_2 = x$ does this mean the solution is $(0,x)$?

Comment: I don't know how you could possibly get $C_{1} = 0$. It would help if you showed your working. Just so you know, the two characteristics are $y/x = c_{1}$ and $(u+1)/(x+y) = c_{2}$.

Comment: My bad it's not 0, but I get x/y instead of y/x? I get ln(x) - ln(y) = c1

Comment: Also could you explain how you got c2, I'm not sure how to do that

Comment: $\ln x - \ln y = c_{1} \implies \ln y - \ln x = -c_{1} = \tilde{c_{1}}$ so $x/y$ and $y/x$ are the same. To get $c_{2}$, use the componendo dividendo rule \begin{align} \frac{dx}{x} = \frac{dy}{y} &= \frac{dx+dy}{x+y} \quad \text{(CD)} \\ \implies\frac{d(x+y)}{x+y} &= \frac{du}{u+1} \end{align} then integrate the last equality.

Answer (score 1):

$$x\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} + y \frac{ \partial u}{\partial y} = 1 + u $$
On the characteristic curves : 
$$\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}=\frac{du}{u+1}$$
A first characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{dy}{y}$ :
$$\frac{y}{x}=c_1$$
A second characteristic equation comes from $\frac{dx}{x}=\frac{du}{u+1}$ :
$$\frac{u+1}{x}=c_2$$
The general solution of the PDE expressed on implicit form $c_2=F(c_1)$ is :
$$\frac{u+1}{x}=F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
$F$ is an arbitrary function.
$$u(x,y)=-1+xF\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)$$
The function $F$ has to be determined according to the condition $u(x,x^2)=x^2$

$x^2=-1+xF\left(\frac{x^2}{x}\right)=1+xF(x)$ for any value of $x$. This determines the function $F(X)$ :

$$F(X)=\frac{X^2+1}{X}=X+\frac{1}{X}$$
We put $F(X)$ into the above general solution where $X=\frac{y}{x}$ :

$F\left(\frac{y}{x}\right)=\frac{y}{x}+\frac{x}{y}$

$u(x,y)=-1+x\left(\frac{y}{x}+\frac{x}{y}\right)$
$$u(x,y)=-1+y+\frac{x^2}{y}$$